# node.js and mongoose, how to bulk insert?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am calling dropbox api "delta" to get all image files in user's account.  right now, I loop through the entries array, then insert one by one. i want to know if there's better way to insert it.

```
    {
      "has_more": false,
      "cursor": "AAHmmLhWV0LhWya_OEKmZhPObxosWt4AHtk66EJiIm2_qoXPuwvyhWyuoH5Ybb_JVE9111PL06D_Td6v5bReJ3jpW_orbjBcYo4111LxRHqR3VKVxdQifemCZ7a-4njLA21TQbrIz5kaYe0vOczv668evAe",
      "entries": [
        [
          "/four/220214_002.jpg",
          {
            "revision": 34,
            "rev": "222005885b",
            "thumb_exists": true,
            "bytes": 105219,
            "modified": "Sun, 23 Feb 2014 14:43:43 +0000",
            "client_mtime": "Sun, 23 Feb 2014 14:43:42 +0000",
            "path": "/four/220214_002.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "icon": "page_white_picture",
            "root": "dropbox",
            "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": "102.8 KB"
          }
        ],
        [
          "/four/250214_002.jpg",
          {
            "revision": 65,
            "rev": "412005885b",
            "thumb_exists": true,
            "bytes": 96909,
            "modified": "Thu, 27 Feb 2014 00:45:28 +0000",
            "client_mtime": "Thu, 27 Feb 2014 00:45:23 +0000",
            "path": "/four/250214_002.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "icon": "page_white_picture",
            "root": "dropbox",
            "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
            "size": "94.6 KB"
          }
        ],
        ...........

      ],
      "reset": true
    }
```

here's my dropboxEntry model.

```
            var mongoose = require('mongoose');

            var dropboxEntrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
                //uid: Number,
                dropbox_uid: Number,
                revision: Number,
                rev: String,
                thumb_exists: Boolean,
                bytes: Number,
                modified: Date,
                path: { type: String, unique: true},
                path1: {type: String, unique: true},
                is_dir: Boolean,
                icon: String,
                root: String,
                size: String,
                deleted: Boolean,
                downloaded: Boolean,
                thumbnail: String
            });

            module.exports = mongoose.model('DropboxEntry', dropboxEntrySchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On high level, mongoose don't seem to support this.(see comments).

So, you can get access to native driver's collection API via: `YourModel.collection`

And then you can do native insert command: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/insert/#dbcmd.insert

which accepts an array of documents.

**Update**:

You can use the [mongodb bulk ops](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) from native driver API as well.

Comment: Note that Model.create() is NOT a bulk insert.  The underlying implementation just does a loop through all the model elements and saves them.